# Confused of the IndexError: list index is out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to coding and python is my first language. Im stuck at my own exercise code.

Code Snippet:

```
a = []
b = []

while len(a) < 11:

    a.append(int(input("enter a number:")))
    if len(a) == 10:
        break

    print ('Original keyed in numbers are:',a)

for element in a:

    if a[element] > 5:
        continue
    b.append(a[element])

print('These are numbers you entered that are less than or equal to 5:',b)
```

I'm getting an IndexError: list index out of range error while executing the above code snippet.

Sample outcome of my code that has error is this:

[Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9fEn.png)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to debug this at all? What does `element` equal when it raises the error? What did you *expect* it to equal?

Comment: There is no a[56], you should just use element > 5

Comment: Please do _not_ include screenshots in your posts. Paste the actual error messages.

Comment: I am sorry DYZ. Ok, so below is the actual result :                              
 
enter a number:2
enter a number:45
enter a number:6
enter a number:3
enter a number:12
enter a number:4
enter a number:0
enter a number:1
enter a number:95
enter a number:65
Original keyed in numbers are: [2, 45, 6, 3, 12, 4, 0, 1, 95, 65]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Python Self Learning/Excercises/List Less Than Ten.py", line 15, in <module>
    if a[element] > 5:
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python `for` loop is a for each loop, so you are directly iterating through values in the list and when the value is less than or equal to 5, you need to add to another list `b`.

**Few corrections**:

```
if len(a) == 10:
    break
```

The above check in your code is not required, because `while` loop is guaranteed to work as long as the condition is `True` and once `len(a)` goes past 10, control moves out of the loop automatically.

Also, you don't need a `continue` if you reversed your `if` condition check.

Finally, this is what you want:

```
a = []
b = []

while len(a) < 11:
    a.append(int(input("enter a number:")))

print ('Original keyed in numbers are:',a)

for element in a:
    if element <= 5:
        b.append(element)

print('These are numbers you entered that are less than or equal to 5:',b)
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop `for element in a` iterates through the values of the list `a`, not through their indexes. At each iteration, `element` is the value of the next list item. The correct loop is shown below:

```
for element in a:    
    if element > 5:
         continue
    b.append(element)
```

An even better approach is to use list comprehension:

```
b = [element for element in a if element <= 5]
```

Comment: Cool, it solved my problem. Very helpful. Thank you very much. As have said I am just started to learn coding. And there are so much more to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this if you are willing to access list elements with their index.

```
a = []
b = []

while len(a) < 11:
    a.append(int(input("enter a number:")))
    if len(a) == 10:
        break

    print('Original keyed in numbers are:',a)

for index in range(len(a)):
    if a[index] > 5:
        continue
    b.append(a[index])

print('These are numbers you entered that are less than or equal to 5:',b)
```